# What is tick(Action action) in action class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the purpose of **tick(Action action)** and **tick(Interaction...actions)** methods present in actions class of Selenium ?

Is it same as clicking on any webElement, if yes then what is the difference between these?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tick(Action action) - You can send only one action object here , whereas in tick(Interaction...actions) - You can pass array of action objects here. Please refer this link for clarification https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-arguments-varargs-in-java/

Comment: What do the docs say? Add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Docs do not contains anything about tick() method, btw I have added the language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tick()` methods were introduced in Selenium 3.2 to make selenium compatible with W3C standards. These methods are used internally, esp the `tick(Interaction)`, for the other methods in the Actions class. The `click()` also uses this method.

Refer to the source if you want to dig deeper - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.11.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java

Comment: So, how would we use it? What benefit would it afford us?

Comment: You don't benefit. It's completely internal to support the new protocol. It's unclear why the methods are public since you can't actually use them in any way without changing selenium code, or hacking your way into the private `InputSource` instances.The way the API is setup it will always put a single interaction in each tick no matter how you add it.